# Combine an array of keys and an array of values to create an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with matching keys and I need to merge the values of both into a new array. I'm beating myself up trying to figure this out. How can I do this?

```
$options = array(
    "0" => true,
    "1" => true,
    "2" => false,
    "3" => true
);

$columns = array(
    "0" => "first",
    "1" => "last",
    "2" => "id",
    "3" => "group"
);

$what_I_need = array(
    "first" => true,
    "last" => true,
    "id" => false,
    "group" => true
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$whatYouNeed = array_combine($columns, $options);
```

That's assuming the arrays are in the correct order. Otherwise:

```
$whatYouNeed = array();
foreach ($columns as $key => column) {
    $whatYouNeed[$column] = $options[$key];
}
```

Comment: $whatYouNeed !!! You win for playing off my what_i_need!

Comment: @Peter lol, i got a good laugh out of it

Comment: @dagon I feel for you... But deceze cracked me up and gave me the answer... what would you of done?

Comment: C'est la vie. I wont lose any sleep over it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$what_I_need = array_combine($columns , $options);
```

[array_combine](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values );

$newArray = array_combine($columns, $options);
print_r($newArray);
```

should give you:

```
array(
    "first" => true,
    "last" => true,
    "id" => false,
    "group" => true
);
```

[PHP array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)